# mysql pam plugin error

Tags: mysql, linux, authentication, pam

I am trying to install mysql pam plugin to use it for user authentication.

I have tried following which are listed in [PAM Pluggable Authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/pam-pluggable-authentication.html). However, I am unable to install the plugin.

1-Adding following lines to my.cnf and restarting mysql service

```
[mysqld]
plugin-load=authentication_pam.so
```

2- Running following statement as root user in mysql command line.

```
INSTALL PLUGIN authentication_pam SONAME 'authentication_pam.so';
```

OUTPUT:

```
ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/authentication_pam.so' (errno: 2 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/authentication_pam.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/pam-pluggable-authentication.html#pam-pluggable-authentication-installation)

> MySQL Enterprise Edition supports an authentication method that
>   enables MySQL Server to use PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules) to
>   authenticate MySQL users. PAM enables a system to use a standard
>   interface to access various kinds of authentication methods, such as
>   Unix passwords or an LDAP directory.

In Enterprise Edition you can get enable it by adding it to config file and restarting the service.

```
[mysqld]
plugin-load-add=authentication_pam.so
```

Or alternatively register at run-time by

```
INSTALL PLUGIN authentication_pam SONAME 'authentication_pam.so';
```

MySQL Community Edition does not have PAM feature.